# RewriteRule url with a parameter to a new url with same parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

With `.htaccess` I want to create a URL forwarding from

- www.example.com/en/?instance_id=1083&lang

to

- www.example.com/en/Veranstaltung/1083/

You can see, that the id is the same, it is possible?
The "en" in the url may change, it shouldn't be a problem.

I tried some different things, like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{query_STRING} instance_id=(.*)$$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [R=301,L]
```

But it didn't work.

I hope, you can help me. I have googled & checked other sites, I haven't been able to find a solution.

If you need more information, only ask me. Its my first question here.

---

Added the original links here:

http://dorfbladl.com/en/   <-- this is the page

If you press one entry of the calendar on the right side, it should be forwarded to

- http://dorfbladl.com/en/Veranstaltung/1914/

This url is one example, the id changes with every entry.

Maybe it could be useful, to find the solution.

Comment: Remove the extra "$" from your cond pattern.

Comment: Thank you for formatting my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} instance_id=([^&]+)&lang
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en/veranstaltung/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I try it, but it does nothing. No forwarding.
Already tried some similar code, but the result are the same.

Comment: I added the original links in the question. Now the "?instance_id..." are missed? In the .htaccess file now : 
`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} instance_id=([^&]+)&lang=.+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en/veranstaltung/%1? [R=301,L]`